# Meu código não aborta a submissão do formulário como deveria

Tags: javascript, html

Eu fiz um formulário, e antes do envio verifico se a pessoa digitou o usuário e a senha. Coloquei isso no evento `submit`, mas parece que não funciona.

O código:

```
<script>
subimitar = function(){
    if(document.getElementByName("usuario").value == ""
      ||
       document.getElementByName("usuario").senha == ""
      ){
        alert("você tem que digitar os campos usuario e senha")
    return false;   
    }     
}
</script>
```

O html:

```
<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="subimitar()">
    Usuario
    <input type="text" name="usuario"/>
    Senha
    <input type="text" name="senha"/>
    <input type="submit" value="entrar"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem dois grandes problemas no seu código:

1. Para funcionar como você quer, você precisa de outro `return` dentro do `onsubmit`:

   ```
   onsubmit="return subimitar()"
   ```
2. Seu JavaScript usa uma função que não existe, `getElementByName`. A função correta é `getElementsByName` (*elements*, no plural), mas neste caso recomendo que você dê um ID para seus campos e use `getElementById`. Outra alternativa é usar `document.querySelector("[name=usuario]").value`, que funciona nos browsers modernos.

Answer (score 3):

Bastaram pequenos ajustes.

Veja as mudanças:

- Acrescentados IDs nos dois inputs do formulário
- Trocados os `getElementByName` por `getElementById`, para retornar indivudualmente cada elemento de nosso interesse
- Acrescentado `return true;` no JS, para deixar explícito o retorno positivo
- Acrescentado o `return` no `onsubmit`, como mencionado pelo @bfavareto, para que o retorno da função realmente volte para o formulário (para bloquear o envio, caso seja `false`)

Script:

```
<script>
function subimitar(){
    if(
        document.getElementById("usuario").value == ""
        ||
        document.getElementById("senha").value == ""
    ){
        alert("você tem que digitar os campos usuario e senha");
        return false;   
    }     
return true;   
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/" method="post" onsubmit="return subimitar()">
    Usuario
    <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario"/>
    Senha
    <input type="text" id="senha" name="senha"/>
    <input type="submit" value="entrar"/>
</form>
```

[Veja em funcionamento no **JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ttjLm/)

Answer (score 1):

Apenas alguma considerações sobre boas práticas:

1. Não use atributos `on*` diretamente no HTML, pois dificulta mudanças e não é escalável.
2. Existe uma maneira melhor de prevenir que um formulário seja enviado.

Faça dessa forma:

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="meu_form">
    Usuario
    <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario"/>
    Senha
    <input type="text" id="senha" name="senha"/>
    <button type="submit">Entrar</button>
</form>
```

Dentro da tag `<head>` do seu HTML, coloque:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    e = e || window.event; // hack p/ IE
    document.getElementById('meu_form').onsubmit = function(e){
        if (document.getElementById("usuario").value == ""
            || document.getElementById("senha").value == ""){
            alert("você tem que digitar os campos usuario e senha");
            e.preventDefault(); // dessa forma o formulário não será enviado   
        }  
    };
};
</script>
```